# C# Adding node in XML error: "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

**XML-1**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "12:30">
        <price>100</price>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </Time>

    <Time Stamp= "14:50">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time> 

    <Time Stamp= "16:30">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time>     
</CurrentStatus>
```

**XML-2**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "17:22">
        <price>40</price>
        <amount>120</amount>
    </Time>               
</CurrentStatus>
```

I am first reading the XML-1 and then trying to insert the **`Time`** node from XML-2 into it (XML-1):

```
//Read first XML
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile1.xml");

//Read second XML
XDocument xDoc2 = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile2.xml");
XElement currentTimeNode = xDoc2.Descendants("Time").ToList()[0]; //first decendent
//Append data
xDoc1.AddFirst(currentTimeNode); //This line throws ERROR
```

**PROBLEM:** I want to add the node as the first child node (add the complete block of `Time` node). The line `xDoc1.AddFirst(currentTimeNode);` throws the following error:

> This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

Comment: What is XDocCurrent? Hard to say what is happening without knowing what that is.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: Sorry, I renamed the variables to ask this question. `XDocCurrent` is basically `xDoc2`. Updated my question.

Comment: *I am reading the first XML and then trying to insert the **`Time`** node from XML-2 into `XDocument xDoc2`.* -- just to clarify, you're trying to insert it into `xDoc1`, correct?

Comment: @dbc: Yes, you are correct. Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add `currentTimeNode` as a child of `xDoc1` -- but `xDoc1` is the XML document itself, which means you are trying to add `currentTimeNode` as a second [XML root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  However, a well-formed XML document must have exactly one root element, and so `xDoc1.AddFirst(currentTimeNode)` throws the exception you are seeing since it already has a root element `<CurrentStatus>`.

Instead you should add `currentTimeNode` to the pre-existing [`Root`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root?view=netframework-4.7.2) of `xDoc1`:

```
xDoc1.Root.AddFirst(currentTimeNode);
```

Or, if there is a chance that `xDoc1.Root` is null (because you are constructing it from scratch in memory rather than loading from a pre-existing file), you could allocate it conditionally:

```
if (xDoc1.Root == null)
    xDoc1.Add(new XElement("CurrentStatus"));
xDoc1.Root.AddFirst(currentTimeNode);
```

Incidentally, it may be simpler and more performant to replace [`ToList()[0]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) with [`First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) because `First()` will not attempt to enumerate and materialize the entire query once the first element is returned:

```
var currentTimeNode = xDoc2.Descendants("Time").First(); //first decendent
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/38miS5).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - for VB'ers that might come across this it would be.

```
    Dim xe1 As XElement
    Dim xe2 As XElement

    xe1 = <CurrentStatus>
              <Time Stamp="12:30">
                  <price>100</price>
                  <amount>1</amount>
              </Time>

              <Time Stamp="14:50">
                  <price>10</price>
                  <amount>5</amount>
              </Time>

              <Time Stamp="16:30">
                  <price>10</price>
                  <amount>5</amount>
              </Time>
          </CurrentStatus>

    xe2 = <CurrentStatus>
              <Time Stamp="17:22">
                  <price>40</price>
                  <amount>120</amount>
              </Time>
          </CurrentStatus>

    xe1.Add(xe2.<Time>) 'add to end
    ' OR
    ' xe1.AddFirst(xe2.<Time>) 'first
```